# replace certain not known words in a string

Tags: python

I'm looking for a more elegant solution to replace some upfront not known words in a string, except `not`,`and` and `or`:

Only as an example below, but could be anything but will always be evaluable with eval())

input: `(DEFINE_A or not(DEFINE_B and not (DEFINE_C))) and DEFINE_A`

output: `(self.DEFINE_A or not(self.DEFINE_B and not (self.DEFINE_C))) and self.DEFINE_A`

I created a solution, but it looks kind a strange. Is there a more clean way?

```
s = '(DEFINE_A or not(DEFINE_B and not (DEFINE_C))) and DEFINE_A'
words = re.findall(r'[\w]+|[()]*|[ ]*', s)
for index, word in enumerate(words):
    w = re.findall('^[a-zA-Z_]+$', word)
    if w and w[0] not in ['and','or','not']:
        z = 'self.' + w[0]
        words[index] = z
new = ''.join(str(x) for x in words)
print(new)
```

Will print correctly:

```
(self.DEFINE_A or not(self.DEFINE_B and not (self.DEFINE_C))) and self.DEFINE_A
```

Comment: Will the variables always be of the form `DEFINE_x`?

Comment: No, they don't. e.g. can be 'LOGGING__ENABLED' or 'CONFIGURE_KEYBOARD_PRESENT'

Comment: Just wanted to make sure if my answer can be more specific but I guess not... Will they always be capitalized?

Comment: Yes, they will always be capitalized.

Comment: Then see my edit for a simplified more efficient version :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you can match only words by using a simple `\w+`. Then, Using a [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) you can ***exclude*** the ones you don't want. Now all that's left to do is use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) directly with that pattern:

```py
s = '(DEFINE_A or not(DEFINE_B and not (DEFINE_C))) and DEFINE_A'

new = re.sub(r"(?!and|not|or)\b(\w+)", r"self.\1", s)

print(new)
```

Which will give:

```
(self.DEFINE_A or not(self.DEFINE_B and not (self.DEFINE_C))) and self.DEFINE_A
```

You can test-out and see how this regex works [here](https://regex101.com/r/61sPTW/1).

---

If the names of your "variables" will **always be capitalized**, this simplifies the pattern a bit and making it much more efficient. Simply use:

```
new = re.sub(r"([A-Z\d_]+)", r"self.\1", s)
```

This is not only a simpler pattern (for readability), but also much more efficient. On this example, it only takes 70 steps compared to 196 of the original (can be seen in the top-right corner in the links).

You can see the new pattern in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/Hhvxed/1).